# What was the equivalent of "Ciao!" in 16th Century Rome?

Tags: single-words, greeting

I've been told that "Ciao!" comes from Venice and, back in the 16th Century, it was not yet used ubiquitously on the Peninsula.

Some sources suggest that "Salve!" could have been used. No doubt it was. But that's not the point.

What would be a common informal greeting, along the lines of "How you doin'?" or "How's all?" or just "Hi there!" in Rome in those days?

Comment: Interesting question! I have a 2-volume collection of *Commedie del Cinquecento*. When I've time, I intend to browse them, hoping that some Roman (or at least well south of Veneto) author is represented there. Just a doubt: what do you mean by saying “that's not the point” about the eventuality that such a greeting might have been “Salve”?

Comment: @DaG: To the best of my knowledge, "Salve!" comes from Latin: Emperor Aurelian would use it to greet Tacitus. It's ancient and therefore outdated. You don't greet folks today by saying, "Greetings, o ye good people!"

Comment: I wasn't meaning the Latin word. [“Salve”](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/salve1/?search=salve%C2%B9) is an Italian word, not outdated at all, and still very much in use nowadays.

Comment: @DaG: Interesting. A word that has survived intact and continues to be in frequent use after 2,500 years, wow.

Comment: Yes, it's not uncommon for Italian words to be identical or very similar to the corresponding Latin ones. (Am I a horrible person if I remark that Tacitus had been dead for almost a century when Aurelian was born? I know it was just a random example involving two famous ancient Romans!)

Comment: @DaG: Yes, you are a terrible person. Since Tacitus (who claimed to be a descendant of the writer) became Aurelian's successor. Imagine that! A bit difficult, that, if you're dead. Which, apparently, he wasn't.

Comment: Oh, that Tacitus! :)

Comment: @DaG: Yeah, that one. Aren't you a terrible person? There is a theory that an interim period took place during which Ulpia, Aurelian's widow, ruled the Empire for about six months, enough to mint some coins with her profile on them, but that's just details.